# Techniques for managing integration that uses data from two objects which can be updated independently or together

Tags: integration, callout, design-patterns, external-services

We have an integration that pushes name, title, manager, and a few other fields from our HR system (a managed package on force.com) to a custom c# endpoint that updates active directory.

Name and Title are on two related objects (Team Member, Employment respectively)

The HR application includes a visualforce page that allows users to update both name + title - so both fields can be updated in one transaction, or just one or the other can be updated.

When the VF page is submitted the integration fires twice - once for the edit to name on Team Member, once for the edit to Title on Employment.

When both name and title are changed, the callout triggered from the edit on team member uses the old title, as the employment would not have been updated yet.

I do not want to rely on these firing in the correct order, so I am trying to think through approaches to ensure the correct data is sent, and ideally only sent once.

In an effort to 'keep things simple', I am using the same integration for either edit.  I pass the team member Id to a flow that handles the callout, and the callout sends all the fields, not just the ones edited.

I am thinking that may be problematic, and that I should use two distinct operations.

I built this integration using 'external services'.  My flow has to use a wait element to avoid throwing an 'uncommitted work pending' error on the callout.  By moving the wait element prior to the queries, I have been able to ensure that both callouts have the correct information, which is a workable solution given the low volume of this integration.

However if there are design patterns that can better address this issue to ensure only one call-out is sent in either scenario, I would like to learn more about this.  Solutions do not need to be limited to external services, as this could easily have been done with a callout.  I imagine there are approaches in code for this, but do not know what to look for.

Note that I need the integration to fire if only name is changed, or if only title is changed, so I cannot just fire off one object.

Thanks

Comment: Code approach: your Visualforce page could talk to an Apex controller which can handle the updates to objects and the callout(s) in whatever sequence you want, here's a [Trailhead tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_custom_controllers).  The _I need the integration to fire if only X but not Y is changed_ sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Take a look at [Identity Connect](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity_connect) as another option

Comment: thanks! the VF page is out of my control.  i think you are right about the XY - my issue is that i'm using the *same* callout for either edit, and we need to refactor to handle these as two distinct entities.  just need to think this through a bit more.

Comment: made some updates to try to frame the problem vs the solution.

Comment: Surely changing VF page (even if it's out of your control) is by far the easiest solution versus going to flow or triggers or events. All of these non-VF alternatives are going to be complex and fragile because there's no way to correlate these two independent edits outside of Salesforce into one "transaction". At best, you can create heuristic rules that will say "oh these two edits were done by the same admin on the same employee in the span of 5 minutes" so they must be the same transaction.

Comment: Thanks I clarified my post to reflect that what I really want to understand is if there is a way (given what I can and can not control) to only send a single callout in the dual object scenario.  My thought was that in full code, you could do something, with static variables or events or something, but not sure what that would look like.  My use-a-wait-and-call-it-good approach seems reasonably reasonable all things considered.  Appreciate your efforts on this thread.